# `ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` - not able to load the page from nested project

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-router

I am trying to load the page from nested project, but getting error as:
`ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` - any one help me here?

both parent and child app has the `app.component.html` with `router-outlet` - will it be an issue?

my project app name (ibo-platform-service):

`app-routing.module` :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'home', component: HomeComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

`app.module.ts` :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const providers = [];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [AppRoutingModule],
  providers,
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


@NgModule({})
export class App1SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: AppModule,
      providers
    };
  }
}
```

my main application router module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'home'
    },
    {
        path: 'home',
        loadChildren: () => import('./../../projects/ibo-platform-service/src/app/app.module').then((m) => m.App1SharedModule)
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

import { App1SharedModule } from './../../projects/ibo-platform-service/src/app/app.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    App1SharedModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when i run this no page loading from nested project app. getting an error as:

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:13)
    at InnerSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at CatchSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:32)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyError (OuterSubscriber.js:7)
    at InnerSubscriber._error (InnerSubscriber.js:14)
    at InnerSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
    at CatchSubscriber._error (Subscriber.js:75)
    at CatchSubscriber.error (Subscriber.js:55)
```

any one figure-out the issue?

Comment: My guess is that the `loadChildren` is causing the issue. Can you create a stackblitz for the same?

Comment: @NicholasK - so how to handle here..

Comment: Also, you have 2 `app.module.ts`? Is that a typo?

Comment: @NicholasK - one is for parent application another one in the project folder. can i share my code in git repo?

Comment: It would still be hard to replicate the issue.. A stackblitz would be the ideal IMHO

Comment: I agree.. it will take long time to reproduce. actually i am trying this, but this is old version i guess : https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201298/discussion-between-user2024080-and-nicholas-k).

Comment: @NicholasK - here is my code: https://github.com/3gwebtrain/multiple-app.git